# C++ How to read string from file into std::string variable with file is FILE's pointer

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I want to read the string from file input into a `std::string` variable.
I declare a FILE pointer to open file:

> `FILE *f = fopen("IN.txt","r");`

And then, I read using `fscanf()` function:

> `std::string tempStr;`
>   `fscanf(f,"%s",tempStr); //Compile Error`
>   `//fscanf(f,"%s",&tempStr);//Runtime Error`

So, I have 2 question:
1. Is it possible to fix the problem above (Still use `FILE *f` and `fscanf()` function)?
2. I'm a C programmer, new to C++. How to solve this problem with the different way?

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    string cities[100];
    FILE * f = fopen("IN.txt", "r");
    fscanf(f,"%d",&n);
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        string tempStr;
        fscanf(f,"%s",tempStr);
        cities[i] = tempStr;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**And the input file (first line is numbers of line):**

```
8
Vancouver
Yellowknife
Edmonton
Calgary
Winnipeg
Toronto
Montreal
Halifax
```

Comment: If you want to use C++ string class, you would make your life easier if you also use C++ file stream classes. They are designed to work together; `FILE*` isn't.

Comment: 1. Of course it can be fixed by using an intermediate char array, but why would you want to.

Comment: You are confusing C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read directly into a `std::string` you can use `FILE*` but you won't be able to use `fscanf()`: the way to do this dance is to create a stream buffer presenting a `FILE*` as something which can be used by an `std::istream`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
class cfilebuf
    : public std::streambuf {
    FILE* file;
    char  c;
    int underflow() {
        int value = fgetc(this->file);
        if (value != EOF) {
            c = value;
            this->setg(&c, &c, &c + 1);
            return c;
        }
        return std::char_traits<char>::eof();
    }
public:
    cfilebuf(FILE* file): file(file) {}
    // to own or not to own? ~cfilebuf() { fclose(this->file; }
};

int main() {
    cfilebuf     sbuf(stdin);
    std::istream in(&sbuf);
    std::string  s;
    if (in >> s) {
         std::cout << "read '" << s << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Note that this stream buffer is geared towards a setup where you'd constantly switch between using `FILE*` and `std::istream*`. If you, reasonably, only use the `std::istream` interface to the `FILE*` you'd rather create a stream buffer which reads an entire buffer: that's a lot more efficient. Also you may want to packet construction of the stream and the stream buffer into just one object:

```
class icfilestream
    : private virtual cfilebuf
    , public std::istream {
public:
    icfilestream(FILE* file)
        : cfilebuf(file)
        , std::ios(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this))
        , std::istream(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this)) {
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah this isn't at all too complex for this OP

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If there are non-trivial requirements it may be necessary use non-trivial solutions. Packaging the stream buffer and the stream into a header and just using it seems simple eough, though. Although, the OP stated that he/she is a C programmer: I'm programming C++ because C is too complex for me to cope with so anything I can come up with is likely trivial for any C programmer!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    string cities[100];
    ifstream f("IN.txt");
    f >> n;
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        f >> cities[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Better still, use `std::vector<string>` for `cities` (this modification is left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: Please explain, I'm new to C++

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the classes I used, and found it lacking? In what way did it fail to satisfy your thirst for knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the stream classes, and `std::getline` or read directly into the string. However, if you really want, in your case can do something like:

```
fscanf(f,"%s",tempStr); // tempStr is declared as char tempStr[N]
cities[i] = std::string(tempStr); // convert to a string
```

Note that you read initially in a `char` buffer (super unsafe btw), then convert it into a `std::string`. But I see no reason to use this code when you can simply do

```
fin >> cities[i]
```

in a loop, where `fin` is a `std::ifstream`